# Can I use my Wi-Fi router to connect my desktop to a Wi-Fi Internet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I am using windows 8.1 and a [TP-Link TL-WR720N](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/?model=TL-WR720N) Wi-Fi Router .

I was using Internet from broadband to my desktop and my laptop with this router (wired connection in desktop and wireless connection in laptop). But now I have a free Wi-Fi connection. I can use it easily in my Laptop, but can’t use it my desktop.

So, I want to use my Wi-Fi Router as a Wi-Fi receiver for my desktop. Is it possible?

Comment: Does it support client mode? Sometimes refered as "Client-Infrastructure". If it does, you can use it to connect to a Wi-Fi network and serve as bridge between your desktop's Ethernet adapter and the Wi-Fi network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has the ability to turn most Wi-Fi network cards to an access point, which can be used to share your Internet connection on your laptop with other devices.

However, there is no built in software to use this feature in a meaningful and easy to use way. So you would need third party open source or commercial software to use this feature.

- [**Virtual Router:**](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) Open source software I have *never* tried.
- [**Connectify Hotspot:**](http://www.connectify.me/) Commercial software I have tried and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you have a separate Wi-Fi connection that you would like to use instead of your broadband connection?

TP-Link has an [article](http://www.tp-link.in/article/?faqid=227) on this :

1. Log into TP-LINK wireless router’s management page.
2. Go to Wireless -> Wireless Settings. Check Enable WDS (Enable WDS bridging).
3. Click Search/Survey. On the pop-up window, find the SSID and channel of your root AP, and hit Connect.
4. Click DHCP-> DHCP Settings page. Choose Disable DHCP Server, and click Save button.

Whether you disable or enable the Wi-Fi AP of the router depends on whether you want your laptop (or other Wi-Fi clients) to also access the internet through the same router.

Comment: I don't think this will work, as it requires the use of WDS, and he does not, I assume, control the server.  (Also, WDS is a security hole)

Answer (score 0):

Its probably not worth it - unless you control the connection to the WIFI server in which case you can use @milindr advice above.

Depending on which TL-WR720N you have - I understand there are very different versions, you may be able to replace the firmware with OpenWRT and then configure it as an AP Client, which will do what you want - of-course you risk bricking your device etc.